# Downscale a 0 - 5volt supply to a millivolt range

Tags: voltage, dac

I am currently at keen novice stage in my understanding of electronics so i hope my question makes sense!

I have a project I am working on that requires the simulation of a sensor. The sensor is measured in millivolts and i have to replicate it's values fairly accurately. I have a 10bit DAC with a 5v supply that i can use to control the voltage but this is not accurate enough on its own as the required range is quite specific. I'm looking to achieve a range of +220 to +365 mvolts. I could use a vref value of 365mv into the DAC but i would only be utilising about 40% of the DAC's range.

My question: Is there a way of further scaling the output voltages to utilize the full 10bit range of the DAC, and if so what would be the best and easiest method?

Thanks for the time.

Mylo

Comment: One way or another, you'll need a negative supply.  Do you have one available already?

Comment: Hi Olin.. No, only a 5v supply available, would an inverting op amp be a possible solution?

Comment: @OlinLathrop The notation is a bit confusing, but I believe the intention is 220mV to 365mV in positive domain :-)

Comment: @Asmyldof Yes that's right, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Why not use a DAC that also has a negative reference?

Answer (score 5):

Just use a voltage divider, assuming a bit of source resistance (50-100 ohms, say) is acceptable.

If you divide to .365/5 then you will still only use a portion of the DAC range, but it will be simpler. (easiest method)

If you divide to 145mV for 5V change at the input and add 220mV (three resistors and a reference voltage) you can use the entire range of the DAC.

Say you use a 49.9 ohm resistor to GND and you have a 5V reference available. Then you could use a 1034.3 ohm and 1635.9 ohm resistor to 5V and DAC output respectively. If I did the sums right that would give you 0.220 to 0.365V output for a DAC output 0~5V.

If you need to  have an accurate output with mA of current flowing (as on the later comment) an op-amp buffer could be used. You can still use the voltage divider as above but it would be better to multiply each value by something like 10. Then a low offset op-amp voltage follower with positive and negative supplies. 1 LSB represents 141uV do pick an op-amp with maybe 50 to 100uV maximum Vos.  There will be many such suitable op-amps that can operate from +/-5V supplies.

Comment: Very clever! :-)

Comment: Thanks Spehro, Yes I had considered the first option as a possibility but i would like to get the full range of the DAC (within reason!). I will try your second solution as this sounds like a simple way of getting the full range. I'll let you know how i get on. Would op amps also be an option?

Comment: Yes, if you need less output resistance. One approach would be to use the same voltage divider, perhaps scaled 10x higher (eg 499 ohms, 10.343K, 16.359K) with a voltage follower. The op amp would need to have very low offset voltage so as not to add much error. You might want to also divide the op amp output voltage 10:1 or add diodes so it could not go too high or low.

Comment: @Mylo: Keep an eye on emulating output impedance of the sensor also. If you use an op-amp use the low error types, and use high precision resistors, else the percentage error will be significant. Using a  dual supply will make sure you can go all the way to zero volts.

Comment: @kabZX is correct, you need a negative supply to allow the simulated sensor to have the correct voltage if it is sinking current. If you want something like a fixed 2 ohm resistance you could add a 2 ohm resistor to the node with feedback.

Comment: Thanks KabZX and Spehro for the feedback, the spec states that there will be a small amount of resistance on the receiving reader and the simulator will need low impedance to withstand a few milliamps of current. With that in mind perhaps op amps are the way to go?

Comment: Yes, mA means that you can't divide down the op amp output too much, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the edited answer, sounds like a nice solution.. So just to confirm, I would need to get a purpose built low offset voltage follower op amp? I have a couple of general purpose op amps but I guess they'd not be much use in this instance? Cheers.

Comment: Most op amps with low Vos are suitable. No need for a special follower, but you need a negative supply voltage as well as positive.